# Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I've got problem with my laravel
I can't post the data

One error says

```
InvalidArgumentException in Validator.php line 2593:
Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.
```

And here it's my code

```
public function postUbah(Request $request, $id)

    $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username'  => 'required|unique:user|min:5',
            'name'      => 'required',
            'group'     => 'required'
        ]);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Here it's my model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;


    protected $table = 'user';


    protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];


    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
```

Comment: is there `username` field in `user` table?

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: then double check your table name ( may be `users` )

Comment: No, my table name is 'user'

Comment: @CandraHerk      'required|min:5|unique:user,username', or 'required|string|username||min:5|unique:user',

Comment: It's still error in the same way.

Comment: @CandraHerk change you table name users then try and let me know

Comment: If I change the table name into users has result "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'evalearn.user' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `user` where `user`.`id` = 1 limit 1)"

Comment: please show us your user table schema, or model

Comment: @CandraHerk change or add your user modal with this $protect table="user",

Comment: @bipin i did not get that

Comment: @CandraHerk open your App/User modal and add this line $protect table="user" and then try and let me know

Comment: @CandraHerk are you sure this is the code that you are using?? please provide the actual code that you are using and your user schema

Comment: @bipin i've already adding the code but still error in the same way.

Comment: @CandraHerk post your App/user model

Comment: Check it @bipin

Comment: @CandraHerk delete your validation and try this   $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username'  => 'required|unique:user,username',
            'name'      => 'required',
            'group'     => 'required',
        ]); clear your cache

Comment: @CandraHerk delete your validation and try this   $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username'  => 'required|unique:user',
            'name'      => 'required',
            'group'     => 'required',
        ]); clear your cache,is your input name is username,check if it start with capital letter

Comment: Clear, but it raised the new error said : "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:"

Comment: @bipin Clear, but it raised the new error said : "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:"

Comment: @CandraHerk refresh your browser it will reslove press crtl + f5

Comment: @bipin CTRL+F5 and the result back to "Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters"

Comment: @CandraHerk  post you blade(view)

Comment: @bipin you can download it on https://www.dropbox.com/s/bn253ggbzvjqt3d/Php%20Error.rar?dl=0

Comment: @CandraHerk it working in my system i just change this thing Evalearn to app what is this Evalearn

Comment: evalearn just my directory folder name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why dont you just use like this

L5.5

```
public function postUbah(Request $request, $id)

    $validator  = $request->validate([
            'username'  => 'required|unique:user|min:5',
            'name'      => 'required',
            'group'     => 'required'
        ]);
}
```

L5.4

```
public function postUbah(Request $request, $id)
    $validator  = $this->validate($request, [
            'username'  => 'required|unique:user|min:5',
            'name'      => 'required',
            'group'     => 'required'
        ]);
}
```

Im aware that your table name is `user`.. make sure your User Model have

```
class User {
    protected $table = "user";
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You've forgot to add the parameter in validation rule to specify the database table column which should be unique in validation rule. You can do it like,

```
 $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username'  => 'required|unique:user,name|min:5',
        'name'      => 'required',
        'group'     => 'required'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "unique:users" instead of "unique:user". This can work for some cases.