# InvalidArgumentException Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a problem with laravel 8 validation please help

1. ```
   public function store(TodoRequest $request){

   $data=request()->all();
   $todo= new Todo();
   $todo->name=$data['name'];
   $todo->Description=$data['Description'];
   $todo->completed=false;
   $todo->save();
   $validated = $request->validated();
   return redirect('/todos');
   ```

   }
2. namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TodoRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
* Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
*
* @return bool
*/
public function authorize()
{
return true;
}

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique|min:6|max:255',
        'Description' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533921/validation-rule-unique-requires-at-least-1-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533921/validation-rule-unique-requires-at-least-1-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make one small change:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:table_name, column_name|min:6|max:255',
        'Description' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

here table_name should be the name of your table and column_name is **'name'** in your case.

Comment: thnakss done bro